# Why notification for List<T> property doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

Why rising `INotifypPropertyChanged` for `List<T>` property doesn't work?

Consider this MCVE:

```
public class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string property = "") =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
}

public class TextWrapper
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => Text;
}

public class ViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public List<string> List { get; } = new List<string>();
    public TextWrapper Text { get; } = new TextWrapper();

    public void AddToList(string text)
    {
        List.Add(text);
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(List));
    }

    public void ChangeText(string text)
    {
        Text.Text = text;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Text));
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    readonly ViewModel _vm = new ViewModel();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = _vm;
    }
}
```

xaml:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding List}" />
```

Calling `_vm.ChangeText(...)` will properly update `TextBlock`, while calling `_vm.AddToList(...)` doesn't update `ListBox` (it will stay empty). Why?

Please note: I know about `ObservableCollection<T>` and I know about two possible workarounds (add setter to `List` and set it to e.g. `null` first and then back or change `DataContext`/`ItemsSource`). I am just curious what is under roof makes `List<T>` more special than `TextWrapper`.

Comment: Side note - not sure if this may be causing the issue, but `List` is a reserved name. Try changing it or prefix it with "@", like `@List`.

Comment: @KamilSolecki It is perfectly legal to name a property with the name of some class. Note also that `List` is a _generic_ class, so it's name is never simply "List", but "List`1", etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a WPF Binding handles the `PropertyChanged` event, it does not update its target property unless the effective value it produces has actually changed.

So unless the `List` property value actually changes (which it doesn't when you add an element), calling

```
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(List));
```

has no effect.

Replace

```
public List<string> List { get; } = new List<string>();
```

by

```
public ObservableCollection<string> List { get; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();
```

and write the `AddToList` method like this:

```
public void AddToList(string text)
{
    List.Add(text);
}
```

---

For your TextWrapper class: Since you directly bind to the TextWrapper instance, the Binding calls its overridden `ToString()` method and hence produces a different value whenever the TextWrapper's `Text` property has changed.

Comment: And? The instances of both properties still. I don't understand. Does it has something to do with some kind of comparer or what? Please note, I am not asking for solution (last paragraph of my question), my question is mostly about difference in `Text` and `List` behavior (properties of `ViewModel`).

Comment: The value of `ViewModel.Text` doesn't change, only `TextWrapper.Text` is (and there is no notification inside `TextWrapper`).

Comment: Perhaps because TextWrapper.ToString() is always evaluated and returns a different string? See how it behaves without overriding ToString.

Comment: Good catch, haven't though about it. With it in mind `TextWrapper` is a failed attempt, thanks.

Comment: @Clemens _"has no effect unless the List property value actually changes"_. You're perfectly right, but can you integrate your answer with some official reference about this behavior, if you know one? I've been searching for a while about MSDN articles or something similar, never found anything about this fact. Seems weird to me that this behavior is not documented at all...

Comment: @Massimiliano Sorry, I don't have such a reference at hand. You may however want to take a look at the [.NET Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/).